# "this" not an acceptable context for ArrayAdapter Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-arrayadapter, android-context

I am currently writing a tabbed application in Android Studios. For whatever reason, "this" is not an acceptable context parameter when creating an ArrayAdapter in a tabbed app whereas it was when I was writing single tabbed applications. Please help.

[image]

Comment: It wants you to pass a Context. Activity extends Context, so you may have seen examples where the adapter was set up from an Activity, and `this` was passed as the Context argument. If you're in a Fragment, you have to pass `context` (a property of Fragment) instead.